# Php won't update to show new sql content

Tags: php, sql

When i update some text on my site and put it into the mySQL DB... the site refreshes but does not update the content to the new content in the Database, and i cannot figure out why, i have removed all cache etc...

Example, i have the page say "Lorem ipsum", and update that with my form to say "Hello there".. the page refreshes but does not change the "Lorem ipsum" before i do a force refresh.. (shift + refresh), and i have removed all cache both in my php documents but also in my 
.htaccess

my php documents cache removal

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Heres the retrival

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Filling` WHERE `group` = '$page'")or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select);
    echo "$row[text]";
    ?>
```

Code for going back:

```
var back = document.referrer;
window.location.replace(back);
```

basicly, with somethings cutoff...
I just cannot figure out how to get this to update properly, thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you see the updated text in MySQL ?

Comment: How are you updating the content, via form post? Or AJAX?

Comment: try MERGING that "Cache-control"

Comment: Yes i see the updated text in mySQL, i use a form post and then redirect back to the previous page with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a querystring with "&time=".time(); which forces the browser to update because it is a new URL... Thanks for all your suggestions though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `print_r($row);` or `var_dump($row);` to see if there is anything in it.

if text is a key in $row then use $row['text']

Comment: thats not an answer, consider commenting that

Comment: I would love to but the system doesn't seem to let me :(

Comment: okay, i'll try that, this does not update either, it just stays at what it was before, untill i do a force refresh

Comment: Just wanted to make sure there was actually some data there.

Comment: Just read your comment on redirecting back to the previous page. What command do you use? history.back(1)?

Comment: var back = document.referrer;
    window.location.replace(back);

Comment: How about location.reload(true); after that?

Comment: i do not have that on...
It goes from index.php to update.php and then back to index.php
If i set location.reload(true); won't it just update to infinity?

Comment: Could you add a variable to the back url and check that variable with $_GET['variable'] in the index page?

Comment: oh yeah, derp :P thanks will try that as soon as i get home :)

Comment: I may just be very dumb... but i can only do this if(isset($_GET['refresh']) && $_GET['refresh'] == "true"){ ?> <script> location.reload(true); </script> <?php  } And that still just reloads infinitely... and if i add a window.location it will just skip the reload... I am really on deep water here :/

Comment: Sorry, try header("location:yourfile"); inside the if-loop. There should be no other output of text or whitespace before this command.

Comment: It sorta works sometimes now, i guess it may just not have made it to the DB in time for the reload... I will see with if i can get this to work with some other methods, else i'll post again later today :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript to redirect back to the previous page using something like

```
history.go(-1);
```

or

```
history.back();
```

Then you are going back in the browser history, which will NOT reload your page's content. Instead, you should use:

```
window.location='[your page URL here]';
```

Or you could just post back to the same page and do your processing at the top of the script.

Comment: var back = document.referrer;
    window.location.replace(back); :)