# php update new SQL content

Tags: php, sql, echo

I'm new to PHP so please have patience and explain it to me like I'm 5.

I have a page where it shows the content of a table from SQL, but whenever I update with php I have for force update my browser to make it display the new content of the table. I got the same problem as this guy but I didn't understand his solution:

[Php won't update to show new sql content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326690/php-wont-update-to-show-new-sql-content)

This is my PHP code for updating the table:

```
<!-- html dok -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>

<?php
$server = "localhost";
$brugernavn = "";
$kode = "";
$db = "";

mysql_connect($server , $brugernavn , $kode) or die(mysql_error());

echo "Forbundet til mysql server<br/>";

mysql_select_db($db)or die(mysql_error());

echo "Forbundet til databasen<br/><br/>";

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nyheder" ) or die(mysql_error());

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
   {
echo "Nyhed: " . $info['nyhed']. "<br/><br/>";
   }

// Update tabel

   if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

       $nyhed = $_POST['nyhed'];

       $tabeldata = "UPDATE nyheder SET nyhed = '$nyhed' WHERE ID ='1'";
       $resultat = mysql_query($tabeldata);
 if($resultat) {
    echo "Din nyhed blev opdateret" . "<a href=get.php>Videre</a>";
   }
 else {
     echo "FEJL";
 }
 }
else {
    echo "Ingen nyheder er blevet opdateret";

}
mysql_close();
?>
```

and this is my code for displaying the table content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT nyhed FROM nyheder WHERE ID='1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$link_address = 'form.php';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $row["nyhed"] . "<br><br>";
         echo "<a href='$link_address'>Opdater</a>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: You'd have to show your update code, and how you go "back" to the updated page. The little snippet you've shown is not useful.

Comment: That said, if you use mysqli (example) please note that num_rows doesn't work correctly (as php.net says), if you use mysql_* than ignore my comment

Comment: Q: Why are you using `mysql_` functions in one piece of code, then hopping over to `mysqli_` in the other?

Comment: It submits the data just fine. After submitting new data to the table I can see it changed in PhpMyAdmin. It's just the display page that I have to force-update (CTRL+SHIFT+R)

Comment: Use a header to the same page then to redirect upon success.

Comment: Fred - I stole some of it from somewhere :(

Comment: Fred - Won't it be looping if it redirects to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use [Php won't update to show new sql content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326690/php-wont-update-to-show-new-sql-content)'s answer change below

```
if($resultat) {
    echo "Din nyhed blev opdateret" . "<a href=get.php>Videre</a>";
   }
```

to

```
if($resultat) {
    echo "Din nyhed blev opdateret" . "<a href=get.php?time=".time().">Videre</a>";
   }
```

this will add current time to get.php as query string (will looks like get.php?time=1417626725) and every time you click the link browser sees get.php as new url and fetch the page again without load it from cache (if it's cached)

Comment: Thank you so much! I love you! I did not know where query strings went.